# How to create newsfeed

Tags: php, web-development, javascript, ajax

I have been working on a project of making a website, and I would like to incorporate a newsfeed (similar to Twitter/fb) where all of my users can see other users updates. I have my login and registration pages, my home pages, and a page to create a post. All of my scripting has been done in php and MySQL, and all of the pages are successfully updating/reading from their respective tables.

So now I need to have everyone posts show up for all to see. I'm not specifically looking for a step by step explanation or someone to do this for me, but I am unsure what to learn next. I've heard people talk of using JavaScript/Ajax/jquery, I've also heard of CMS, but I'm unclear exactly how this is supposed to be facilitated.

Do I need to just get a book on JavaScript and start from the beginning? Can I do this with just php?  Or is there a more specific topic I can just start learning from to accomplish building this newsfeed?

Thx

Comment: Sorry but the question is too board, opinionated and also off-topic due to the nature of the question (programming). Please visit our help centre for further advice and to save further disappointment.